# Imageresizer S3Reader plugin and IAM Roles

Tags: imageresizer

According to this pull request https://github.com/imazen/resizer/pull/178
you are fixed issue with AWS IAM roles(EC2 Profiles) but this changes were not merged to a master.
Are you going to release this feature. It affects security of the application and looks important to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was not merged into master. Could you please check this https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/master/Plugins/S3Reader2/S3Reader.cs ?

Also could you please clarify from which branch do you ship release versions? I expected that you don't ship official releases from develop branch and that's why that pull request is not available in our version of S3Reader2 plugin.

We'r using S3Reader2 with the following header:

```
// Type: ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2.S3Reader2
// Assembly: ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: FBCB569C-2711-4F60-A416-B504F816CEA7
```

It does not contain an additional if else statement in the constructor:

```
public S3Reader2(NameValueCollection args)
      : this()
    {
      this.LoadConfiguration(args);
      this.UseHttps = args.Get<bool>("useHttps", args.Get<bool>("useSsl", this.UseHttps));
      this.Region = args.GetAsString("region", "us-east-1");
      this.SetAllowedBuckets((IEnumerable<string>) args.GetAsString("buckets", "").Split(new char[1]
      {
        ','
      }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args["accessKeyId"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args["secretAccessKey"]))
        this.S3Client = new AmazonS3Client(args["accessKeyId"], args["secretAccessKey"], this.s3config);
      else
        this.S3Client = new AmazonS3Client((AWSCredentials) null, this.s3config);
    }
```

Thank you in advance,
Alex.

Answer (score 0):

This was merged two years ago, and has been shipped.